# Is there any or preferably full documentation for OpenERP7?

Tags: documentation, odoo

Is there any or preferably full documentation for OpenERP**7** for free in any format?
Sadly I've only found documentation for v6.1.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation about OpenERP 7 can be found here:
http://openerp-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Useful information can be found here:
https://www.odoo.com/nl_NL/forum/help-1/question/where-is-openerp-v7-documentation-6817

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [OpenERP-7 Document](http://doc.openerp.com/trunk/developers/index.html) for OpenERP version-7. It is not full document but trunk.

Comment: this is  a dead link

Answer (score 0):

You can go to http://dipleo.fr  ! We try to put here all OpenERP Documentation that we found and we write tutorials.

Comment: this is  a dead link